# Java Error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java

Here is this simple code from my book it produces error message in netbeans and in compile version (.class) version running through Command prompt.

Error Message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at intocm.Intocm.main(Intocm.java:17)
```

Simple Program to convert inches to centimeter.

```
package intocm;

public class Intocm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        double inches;
        inches = Double.valueOf(args[0]).doubleValue();
        double cm;
        cm = inches * 2.54;
        System.out.println(cm + "Centimeters");
    }
}
```

The Line which Causes error is

```
inches = Double.valueOf(args[0]).doubleValue();
```

I don't know why this array "args" causing this error please help me in understanding this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not passing command line arguments. `args[0]` is expecting a command line argument.

IF you are running it from command line try this:

```
java Intocm 12.0
```

In eclipse

```
Run---> Run Configuration--->
                            Arguments Tab--->
                                            give program arguments-->
                                                                  apply---> run
```

Comment: is there anyway i can run this in software like netbeans or eclipse without any error.

Answer (score 1):

The `args` parameter in a class's `main` method is supplied by command line arguments. You are not invoking the jar with any command line args, so the array has no zero element.

Answer (score 1):

If `args[0]` is causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, then you didn't supply any command-line parameters.  Test `args.length`; if it's `0`, then handle the error.